# INT type with Max Size in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

How can we indicate a max size for the type `int`, `integer` or `number` in a SQL Server database?

For example, with `varchar` we can indicate the max size: `varchar(40)`.
What's the equivalent for the numbers?

Comment: One solution could be to create a Trigger as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868213/is-that-somehow-possible-to-set-a-maximum-value-for-a-column-at-sql-server-2008

Comment: A check constraint limits the acceptable range of values, but the only influence over the amount of storage used is which of the built in types you select - so there's no way, for instance, to get an integral type that will only use 6 bytes of storage.

Comment: if not an integral , is there a way to specify this max Size for a numeric value in general ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define a `CHECK` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
(
   SomeIntColumn INT
      CONSTRAINT CHK_YourTable_SomeIntColumn 
        CHECK (SomeIntColumn >= 0 AND SomeIntColumn <= 9999),
   .......
)
```

You can define a **range** of possible values for your numeric column that way. With this `CHECK` constraint in my sample, you can limit your `INT` column to a maximum of 4 digits.

**Update**

For the `INT` style datatypes, you **cannot** define a number of digits in SQL Server directly - there's no `INT(4)` or anything like that. You'll need to use a `CHECK` constraint as I showed.

The types `decimal` (and `numeric`) do support precision and scale:

```
decimal(p, s)
```

where `p` is the precision (total number of digits) and `s` is the scale (number of digits after the decimal point).

So a `decimal(10,4)` gives you **10** digits in total, **4** of which are after the decimal point, so you can have values like

```
     0.0000
123456.1234
```

and so on

Comment: yes , thank you , but how do i refer to this max number 9999 with the ColumnSize of the schematable in my code later ? because i must use the max Size for some verifications in my code

Comment: @manu: you **cannot** set a "max size" for an `INT` column - it's always **4 bytes** in size.

Comment: then if not for an int , can i set a max size for other numeric types ? ( numbers )

Answer (score 1):

They are already defined by that type you use, 
for bigint that would be 8 bytes. See [reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/sql-server-data-type-reference)

Comment: yes , but i meant when i want an int that contains no more than 4 numbers , for example an attribute in database Key1 that should be a numeric and its max Size of numbers is 4  when i enter 11158 it won't accept it

Comment: Oh, check marc_s 's answer